# Managing One To Many Relationships With Entity Framework Core

Tags: .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am building an API using .NET Core and I am trying to insert records into many tables in relationships. I have tables Client, Shipment, ShipmentDetail and Product

I am getting error when i am trying to insert shipmentDetails into shipment. The error is: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_ShipmentDetails_Products_ProductId". The conflict occurred in database "MyDb", table "dbo.Products", column 'Id'.

Classes:

```
 public class Client
{
        public int ClientId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; } = String.Empty;
        public string Adress { get; set; }
        public List<Shipment> Shipments { get; set; }
}
   public class Product : IEntity
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }    
    }

public class Shipment
{
        public int ShipmentId { get; set; }
        public DateTime TimeCreated { get; set; }
        public string ShippingAddress { get; set; }
        public int DeliveryCost { get; set; }
        public string OrderNumber { get; set; }
        public DateTime EstimatedDate { get; set; }
        public int ClientId { get; set; }

        public Client Client { get; set; }

        public List<ShipmentDetail>? ShipmentDetails { get; set; }
        public List<ShipmentStatu>? ShipmentStatus { get; set; }
}

public class ShipmentDetail
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string DeliveryNumber { get; set; }
        public string TrackingNumber { get; set; }

        public Shipment Shipment { get; set; }
        public int ShipmentId { get; set; }

        public Product Product { get; set; }
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
}
```

What I have tried

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<List<Shipment>>> AddShipments(ShipmentDto request)
{
 
    var client = _context.Clients.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == request.ClientName) 
     ?? new Client
        {
            Name = request.ClientName,
            Adress = request.ClientAdress
        };

    var newShipment = new Shipment
    {
        TimeCreated = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.GetDateTimeFormats()[0]),
        ShippingAddress = request.ShippingAddress,
        DeliveryCost = request.DeliveryCost,
        OrderNumber = "x" + DateTime.Now.ToString("MMddyy"),
        EstimatedDate = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.AddDays(2).GetDateTimeFormats()[0]),
        ShipmentDetails = new List<ShipmentDetail>{
           new ShipmentDetail{
                  DeliveryNumber = request.DeliveryNumber ,
                  TrackingNumber=request.TrackingNumber,    
           }
        }
    };

   if(client.Shipments == null)
      client.Shipments = new List<Shipment>();

   client.Shipments.Add(newShipment);

   if(client.ClientId == default)
      _context.Clients.Add(client);
   else _context.Clients.Update(client)

   _context.SaveChanges();

   return Ok(newShipment);
}
```

Does anyone have an idea ? Kind Regards...

Comment: while you add `ShipmentDetail`,  productId not assigned a value so productId would being 0.

Comment: How can i fix it any idea?

Comment: Either productId will be nullable or it will be unique assign as `new ShipmentDetail{ DeliveryNumber = "Example", TrackingNumber="Example", ProductId: UniqueId}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple issues and suggestions when working with related collections.

First, when loading entities with the intention of working with their children, be sure to eager load their children:

```
var client = _context.Clients
    .Include(p => p.Shipments)
    .SingleOrDefault(p => p.Name == request.ClientName) 
    ?? new Client
    {
        Name = request.ClientName,
        Adress = request.ClientAdress
    };
```

Where you expect 1 or 0 results, use `SingleOrDefault()` rather than `FirstOrDefault()`. Using the "First" flavour methods can conceal bad data assumptions where your code is not selective enough resulting in the potential for the wrong data to be updated. The proper use of "Single" methods assert this at runtime and would throw the moment they encounter an invalid data state for the assumed uniqueness.

If you know there could be more than one match and only want the first particular match, then you can use `FirstOrDefault()` but should include an `OrderBy()` to ensure the selection is predictable and repeatable. I know Nick Chapas recently released a video about where `SingleOrDefault()` could impose performance costs compared to `FirstOrDefault()`, but that only applies to using it against in-memory collections. When EF builds a query, `FirstOrDefault` generates a `TOP(1)` while `SingleOrDefault` generates a `TOP(2)` equivalent query.

Next, you should avoid ever "setting" collection references in entities outside the construction of the entity. EF works with proxies for change tracking so setting a collection to a new `List<T>` can muck things up with existing entities. I recommend changing the collection references in Client to something like:

```
public virtual ICollection<ShipmentDetail> ShipmentDetails { get; internal set; } = new List<ShipmentDetail>();
public virtual ICollection<ShipmentStatus> ShipmentStatus { get; internal set; } = new List<ShipmentStatus>();
```

Now you can use these collections immediately on a new Client instance, or access them without worrying about #null checks.  There should never be code anywhere in the code base that attempts to set these to a new collection.

The resulting code would end up looking like:

```
var client = _context.Clients
    .Include(p => p.Shipments)
    .SingleOrDefault(p => p.Name == request.ClientName) 
    ?? new Client
    {
        Name = request.ClientName,
        Adress = request.ClientAdress
    };

var newShipment = new Shipment
{
    TimeCreated = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.GetDateTimeFormats()[0]),
    ShippingAddress = request.ShippingAddress,
    DeliveryCost = request.DeliveryCost,
    OrderNumber = "x" + DateTime.Now.ToString("MMddyy"),
    EstimatedDate = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.AddDays(2).GetDateTimeFormats()[0]),
    }
};
newShipment.ShipmentDetails.Add(new ShipmentDetail
{
    DeliveryNumber = request.DeliveryNumber,
    TrackingNumber = request.TrackingNumber    
});

client.Shipments.Add(newShipment);

if(client.ClientId == default)
    _context.Clients.Add(client);

_context.SaveChanges();

return Ok(newShipment);
```

The other notable here was that we don't need to call `_context.Update`, instead, let EF's change tracking manage tracking what details in the client and related entities has occurred. When using DTOs / ViewModels I'd recommend also being consistent and avoiding sending Entities in their place, so I would consider updating the returned object in the response to a DTO.

**Edit**: Example for associating a Product to a new ShipmentDetail. Say you have a Product selected for the new shipment detail, Product ID #35 and a ShipmentDetail contains a collection of Products. (Many-to-Many relationship) This applies if it contains a single Product reference as well. (Many-to-One) What we don't want to do is:

```
var product = new Product{ Id = 35 };
shipmentDetail.Products.Add(product);

// ...
_context.SaveChanges();
```

This will result in one of two things where a row for Product ID #35 already exists. Either we get an exception for a Duplicate PK as EF tries to insert a product for the same ID, or it will attempt to insert a new Product with an ID of #645 or whatever happens to be the next available Product ID if that table is set up for an Identity column on it's PK. This is a common problem when a complete Product "entity" is deserialized as part of the POST request and added to the new entity. The DbContext isn't tracking that instance so it treats it as a new one.

One workaround which will work some/most of the time would be to attach the product to the DbContext:

```
var product = new Product{ Id = 35 };
_context.Attach(product);
shipmentDetail.Products.Add(product);

// ...
_context.SaveChanges();
```

This will work some times, but it can result in an exception in a situation where the DbContext already happens to be tracking that specific Product ID.

The safest way to deal with the scenario is to fetch the Product and associate it that way:

```
var product = _context.Products.Single(x => x.Id == 35);
shipmentDetail.Products.Add(product);

// ...
_context.SaveChanges();
```

This ensures that EF associates the existing Product to the shipment detail. Developers can lean to avoid doing this because it means a trip to the DB. However, loading entities by ID is quite fast, and it gives the benefit of asserting that the ID #35 is actually a valid Product ID.

Going back to the attach scenario. There is a safer way to do this without the DB round trip, however it's still not foolproof:

```
var product = _context.Products.Local.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == 35);
if (product == null)
{
    product = new Product{ Id = 35 };
    _context.Attach(product);
}
shipmentDetail.Products.Add(product);
```

// ...
_context.SaveChanges();

However, the downside of this approach (other than adding more code just to try and avoid a trip to the DB) is that there is still no assertion that the Product ID #35 actually exists in the database. If it doesn't, the above code would fail on the `SaveChanges`.

In the Many-To-One scenario if a Shipment Detail contains a Product ID and product reference, a quick hack to do an insert is to just set a ProductId field on the new ShipmentDetail record being inserted:

```
shipmentDetail.ProductId == productId;
_context.SaveChanges();
```

The downside is that we cannot populate a Product reference for the same reasons above without either loading the Product or attaching it (after checking that no reference is already tracked) This means any further code that might inspect the Shipment Detail we just created won't be able to access any Product related details until the Shipment Detail is reloaded. (such as if we pass the newly created Shipment Detail back to the view, or to Automapper to build a view model) This is why the performance investment of going to the DB to fetch and associate the Product is worthwhile, it is the safest, least code, and most useful.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment Steve, its works ! can i ask you one more thing? how can i instert product into shipmentDetails

Comment: If by a Product you mean a reference to an existing row in the database and the shipment details contains either a reference to a single product or a collection of products, the easiest way is to fetch that Product by ID from the DbContext and add/associate it to the new ShipmentDetail. You don't want to create a new Product instance with an existing ID and add it, because EF will treat any untracked instance it encounters as new and try and insert. Attaching that new instance will work but you first need to check if an instance is already tracked, and if so, use that.

Comment: I added some detail to the answer with scenarios around associating a Product to the new shipment detail.